# Create custom like button in laravel4

Tags: php, laravel

Can someone tell me, step by step how can I create a functional like button in my app? Explain how it works so I just don't have to rely on your codes, and can create my own like button by my own. And I hope someone will guide me because i don't know how this thing works, how many database tables I have to create, or should I use javascript. My app can display all post from database and this is my code so far.

from my controller:

```
public function dashboard()
{
    $mytime = Carbon\Carbon::now();
    $user = Auth::user();
    $posts = Post::where('reviewed', '=' , 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    $url = asset('img/logo.gif');
    $this->layout->content = View::make('interface.dashboard', 
        array('posts' => $posts->paginate(9)))
        ->with('img', $url)
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('date', $mytime);

}
```

and my view:

```
<div class="dashboard">
    @foreach (array_chunk($posts->getCollection()->all(),4) as $row)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($row as $post)
                <article class="col-md-4 effect4" class="dash-box">
                    <p></p>
                    <div><img src="{{ asset('img/' . $post->image) }}" /></div>
                    <b><a href="{{ URL::action('LoginUsersController@viewPost' , array('id' => $post->id))}}">{{$post->title}}</a></b>
                    <hr>
                    <d>{{$post->created_at->toFormattedDateString()}}</d>
                </article>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <div class="page">
        {{$posts->appends(Request::only('difficulty'))->links()}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified if the like should be for user or for the post, I am guessing it is for the post. In ether case you should not create a new table as you can add a "number_of_like" column to your Post table.

Then create a like button within your @foreach($row as $post) and it would look like this:

```
{{ Form::open(['method' => 'POST', 'route' => [ 'post_path', $post->id ] ) }}
    <button type="submit" >Like</button>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Above you are posting the post id to post_path which is then defined in your routes.php:

```
Route::post('post/{id}', [
    'as' => 'post_path',
    'uses' => 'PostController@update'
]);
```

now in your PostController you will receive the id as update method parameter and can use it to find post and update number_of_likes:

```
public function update($id)
{
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->number_of_likes++;
        $post->save();
return Redirect::back();
}
```

When creating a post which should be from in PostController@create you should initialize number_of_likes with zero.

In the end to show how many likes post have, just add it before the button :

```
{{$post->number_of_likes}} <button type="submit" >Like</button>
```

Note the whole thing can be done in many different ways, but this is one basic way of doing it. When you get this working then you can try to improve it with some javascript if needed.

Comment: Thank you sir for answering my question and posting your codes. i will try this now and try to see where will this lead me but anyway thank you again